Vcpkg in CMake solution and added CMake project
I'm trying to set up file structure for my future projects. The general idea is to have something like this:
MySolution
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── MyProject
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── vcpkg.json
    ├── src
    │   ├── main.cpp
    │   └── utils.cpp
    ├── include
    │   ├── myproject.h
    │   └── utils.h
    └── vcpkg_installed
        └── x64-windows
            └── imgui
                └── include
                    └── imgui.h

The problem is that MySolution/MyProject/CMakeLists.txt works fine and vcpkg downloads and includes libs just as planned when I create solution with ./cmake. But if I add MyProject to MySolution CMake stops with errors unable to find, for example, imgui, that is successfully downloaded and added if I run ./cmake for MySolution/MyProject/CMakeLists.txt alone.
MySolution/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project("MySolution")

# Include the project CMakeLists
add_subdirectory("MyProject")

MySolution/MyProject/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)


set(VCPKG_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY "vcpkg_installed/vcpkg/x64-windows/include/")

set(VCPKG_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../outer gits/vcpkg")
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")

# Enable vcpkg
include(${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE})

project(MyProject)

# ... rest of your CMakeLists.txt file ...
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
include_directories("${VCPKG_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY}")

configure_file (
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/config.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h"
  )

add_executable(cmake_test "src/main.cpp")

find_package(imgui CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(cmake_test PRIVATE imgui::imgui)


MySolution/MyProject/vcpkg.json
{
    "dependencies":[
        {
            "name": "imgui",
            "features": [
                "docking-experimental",
                "opengl3-binding",
                "glfw-binding"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "builtin-baseline": "4bee3f5aae7aefbc129ca81c33d6a062b02fcf3b",
    "overrides": [
        { 
            "name": "imgui", 
            "version": "1.90"
        }
    ]
}

And here is the error I get running MySolution/CMakeLists.txt:
CMake Error at *path*/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:859 (_find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "imgui" with any of
  the following names:

    imguiConfig.cmake
    imgui-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "imgui" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "imgui_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "imgui"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  MyProject/CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Looks like I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out how to manage dependances with vcpkg if I have solution with several projects. I have read that there are difficulties if I try to make one vcpkg_installed for all projects in solution but it seems like it should work for projects.

I'd suggest you add CMakePresets.json to set CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE rather than hard-coding it into your CMakeLists. Same with VCPKG_ROOT.
